# laravel remember me not working in chrome work in firefox

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, laravel, remember-me

As I mentioned in my post in my Laravel 4.1 application I have the "Remember me" option.

When I connect in chrome with "Remember me" checked and close the browser and open it, it's working, even when I don't check it!

But with Firefox it work perfectly. When I check "Remember me", close then open the browser I'm still connected.

When I don't check it and connect, close then open the browser it return me to the login form with error message.

I don't understand why it's not working in chrome.

```
 else if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember)) {

     return Redirect::intended('/');
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because, probably `Chrome` is still running in the background after you've closed the browser. Try to disable `Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed` feature, follow these steps:

- Open `chrome://settings`
- Click `Show advanced settings`
- Go to to System section (downward) and disable `Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed`. 
  This will force the `Chrome` browser to close completely and then it'll delete the session cookies as well.

This is a `common` problem using `Chrome` and I've faced it before and solved it right this way.