# Laravel ajax response woking in chrome but not firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, csrf

I am using a link to delete a record.

html

```
<button class="button link alert" data-src="admin/category/{{ $category['id'] }}" data-method="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash danger"></i></button>
```

ajax

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

function http_post(url, postData){
return $.ajax({
    url:url,
    data: postData,
    type: 'DELETE'
});
```

route

```
Route::resource('category', 'CategoriesController');
```

response

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    return response()->json(['status'=>1]);
}
```

Now I am getting the response in chrome but not firefox.

Comment: Have you tried in private / incognito mode on both browsers after clearing your views ?

Comment: What means "not working"? What's your expectation and what's the actual result?

Comment: php doesn't have a delete method use POST

Comment: I am returning a value from controller to check whether the ajax is working. I am getting the response in chrome but firefox gives status error. There was no error code provided by firefox.

Comment: @AbelD you console what does it say?

Comment: @madalinivascu php doesn't have delete method ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen i mean delete requests

Comment: @madalinivascu You mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33366525/3282633) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel remember me not working in chrome work in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627194/laravel-remember-me-not-working-in-chrome-work-in-firefox)